# grep using a contents of a file to find what is missing

Tags: shell, csv, grep

I am trying find the rows of a file which dont appear in any rows of collection of other files

i have put togther the following code, but it only seems to work for the last row in the `names.csv`

names.csv is a single column file with no header which looks like this:

```
Fred
Jack
Ian
Louis
Ash
```

The records/**.csv files are 800mb+ files of records with lots of columns. The name column values are wrapped in double quotes for what its worth...

```
name,email,etc..
"Fred",fred@fred.com...
"Ash",ash@ash.com...
"Jack",jack@jack.com...
```

My chained command:

`grep -whof names.csv records/*.csv | grep -vFf /dev/stdin names.csv > missing.csv`

```
missing.csv
Fred
Jack
Ian
Louis
```

This finds `Ash` is in one of the files and I end up with all the others still in missing.

How do I use the contents of a file to grep properly?

Comment: can you create a minimal example that shows the problem and will serve for testing purposes? you have already shown `names.csv`, create two small sample files, say `foo.csv` and `baz.csv` with few lines each, and another sample for `topxyz.csv` and then show complete expected output for these samples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. With *GNU* `cut` (*Linux*):

   ```
   cut -k2 -d '"' records/*.csv | sort -u | grep -vf - names.csv
   ```
2. With *BSD* `cut` (*BSD*, *OSX*)

   ```
   cut -f2 -d '"' records/*.csv | sort -u | 
     grep -vf /dev/stdin names.csv
   ```

Comment: I had an issue with the `-k2` argument (cut: illegal option -- k) probably because I'm on OSX and not Linux, so switched to `-f2` so the command looks like 

`cut -f2 -d '"' records/*.csv | sort -u | grep -vf /dev/stdin names.csv`

It works perfectly, with the expected outcome! Thank you! =D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking at names that aren't part of the `records/*.csv` but are listed in `names.csv`.

If so, you can use this `awk` script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{b[$2]}END{for(i in a)if(!(i in b)) print i}' names.csv FS='"' records/*.csv
```

The first block statement `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}`  fills the array `a` with the content of `names.csv`.

The next block `{b[$2]}` fills the array `b` with the names (in the first column) of files `records/*.csv`.

The last block statement is looking up names in `a` that are not in `b` and print them.